# Android Java Parsing XML via Web

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to parse data via XML and it's working but the only problem is it is returning the last line of the tag. I'm using Lyrics Wiki just to test out

http://lyrics.wikia.com/LyricWiki:API

For the example post on their site with artist cake and song dime the return value I get is "When a crumpled up [...]"

My code looks as such:

public class ExampleHandler extends DefaultHandler{

```
    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    private boolean in_outertag = false;
    private boolean in_innertag = false;
    private boolean in_mytag = false;

    private ParsedExampleDataSet myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();

    // ===========================================================
    // Getter & Setter
    // ===========================================================

    public ParsedExampleDataSet getParsedData() {
            return this.myParsedExampleDataSet;
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Methods
    // ===========================================================
    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
            this.myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
            // Nothing to do
    }

    /** Gets be called on opening tags like:
     * <tag>
     * Can provide attribute(s), when xml was like:
     * <tag attribute="attributeValue">*/
    @Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                    String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equals("LyricsResult")) {
                    this.in_outertag = true;
            }else if (localName.equals("lyrics")) {
                    this.in_mytag = true;
            }
    }

    /** Gets be called on closing tags like:
     * </tag> */
    @Override
    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
                    throws SAXException {
            if (localName.equals("LyricsResult")) {
                    this.in_outertag = false;
            }else if (localName.equals("lyrics")) {
                    this.in_mytag = false;
            }
    }

    /** Gets be called on the following structure:
     * <tag>characters</tag> */
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
        if(this.in_mytag){
            myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedString(new String(ch, start, length));
        }
```

}
}

and...

public class ParsedExampleDataSet {
    private String extractedString = null;
    private int extractedInt = 0;

```
public String getExtractedString() {
        return extractedString;
}
public void setExtractedString(String extractedString) {
        this.extractedString = extractedString;
}

public int getExtractedInt() {
        return extractedInt;
}
public void setExtractedInt(int extractedInt) {
        this.extractedInt = extractedInt;
}

public String toString(){
        return this.extractedString;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

fixed just needed to put chars into stringbuilder